# MySQL - Delete rows in one table if a value in a different table isn't present in any rows

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve the following issue.  I've been looking for a solution for about a week and thus far, no luck.

We have a site where we need to remove tens of thousands of cities if they don't have any associated users.

So basically, we have to delete form table "cities" if the "city id" doesn't exist in table "users".  Let's say, we need to delete any rows from 'cities' if 'cities.city_id' isn't found in the column 'users.city_id' meaning no users are associated with that city.

Basically what needs to happen is that for each single row in 'cities', MySQL needs to look at every row in users.city_id to see if the value exists, if yes then it moves on to the next row, if not it deletes the row in cities, then moves to the next row.

I'm not even sure if a query like this one is possible... any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Without having access to your complete schema, here's my attempt below. Do backup your database before performing any delete operation in case things go haywire, I don't wanna get sued :(

```
DELETE FROM cities WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT city_id FROM USERS);
```